# How to run multiple apps with the same test case in appium

Tags: node.js, mobile, android-emulator, appium

I need to test two apps in the same test case in Appium ( android ) 
for example, write test case to publish ads on app (A) and see the ad in the second app (B). Also, Can I run on emulator ? or should apply on real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research, I found the solution. the simple way to do that by define new driver with the selected app and this cause to close the first app and open new one. 
Example Code

```
return driver
.elementById('username')
   .click()      
   .init(Common.SelectApp(apps.AppName))  //Open new app ( the code below)
   .setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)
   .elementById('username')
   .click()
```

// Select App function:

```
var desired = process.env.npm_package_config_sauce ?
    _.clone(require("./helpers/caps").android18) :
    _.clone(require("./helpers/caps").android19);
   return desired.app = App Name;
```

This code from appium examples (Node)